# Pandas running division for a column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to Pandas and would love some help   I'm trying to take:

```
factor
1
1
2
1
1
3
1
2
```

and produce:

```
factor  running_div
1            1
1            1 
2            0.5
1            0.5
1            0.5
3            0.1666667
1            0.1666667
2            0.0833333
```

I can do it by looping through using .iloc, but trying to use vector math for efficiency.   Have looked at rolling window and using .shift(1), but can't get it working.   Would appreciate any guideance anyone could provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use numpy `ufunc.accumulate`

```
df['cum_div'] = np.divide.accumulate(df.factor.to_numpy())

   factor   cum_div
0       1  1.000000
1       1  1.000000
2       2  0.500000
3       1  0.500000
4       1  0.500000
5       3  0.166667
6       1  0.166667
7       2  0.083333
```

Comment: Such an elegant, clean solution!  I've bought a good Pandas book and it helped greatly.   It's clear I need to do the same for Numpy.   Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame([1,1,2,1,1,3,1,2], columns=["factor"])
df["running_div"]=df["factor"].iloc[0]
df["running_div"].loc[df.index[1:]]=1/df["factor"].loc[df.index[1:]]
df["running_div"]=df["running_div"].cumprod()

print(df)
```

Output:

```py
factor  running_div
0       1     1.000000
1       1     1.000000
2       2     0.500000
3       1     0.500000
4       1     0.500000
5       3     0.166667
6       1     0.166667
7       2     0.083333

[Program finished]
```

Answer (score 1):

A cumulative division is done by keeping the first element, and them cumulatively multiplying by the inverse of all next elements until the end.

Hence, using `np.cumprod`

```
df['division'] = np.cumprod([df.factor.iloc[0], *1/df.factor.iloc[1:]])
```

---

```
   factor  division
0       1  1.000000
1       1  1.000000
2       2  0.500000
3       1  0.500000
4       1  0.500000
5       3  0.166667
6       1  0.166667
7       2  0.083333
```